# You can write ${\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)^x}$ as ${2^{ - x}}$ , can the same be done with ${\left( {\frac{2}{3}} \right)^x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

You can write ${\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)^x}$ as ${2^{ - x}}$ as:
${\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)^x} = {({2^{ - 1}})^x} = {2^{ - x}}$

But what about ${\left( {\frac{2}{3}} \right)^x}$?
Can it be written so that it has a negative $x$ exponent? I am asking this because for base 'b' of an exponential function where $0<b<1$ is makes sense for me to write it this way as it is intuitive, i.e. ${\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)^x} = {2^{ - x}}$, it is intuitive because it allows me to think of the graph of this function as the reflection of the graph of the function $f(x) = {2^x}$ in the y-axis. Is it possible for me to to think of functions such as: $${\left( {\frac{2}{3}} \right)^x},{\left( {\frac{4}{9}} \right)^x},{\left( {\frac{2}{5}} \right)^x},{\left( {\frac{6}{7}} \right)^x},etc$$
In this way?

Comment: That would be $(\frac32)^{-x}$. But is it a reflection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes down to $a^{-1}=\frac{1}{a}$. This gives you
$$ 2^{-x} = (2^x)^{-1} = \frac{1}{2^x} = \left(\frac 1 2\right)^x.$$
From this you also get
$$ \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{-x}. $$

Comment: Or you could say it is $2^x3^{-x}$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's what I saw it as after some messing about, thing is it provides no intuition graph-wise you know?

Comment: @Assad Not sure what that question means. You'll have to be specific.